# parallelism and accessing memory locations

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#intro.races-2

> Two expression evaluations conflict if one of them modifies a memory
> location ([intro.memory]) and the other one reads or modifies the same
> memory location.

Does the conflict mentioned in the quote refer to when it occurs literally at the same time (**parallel**) or when it occurs **concurrently** (i.e., because of the context switching) or **both cases**?

I can only see it as a problem when it happens literally at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the definition of "conflict" is concerned, the standard *does not care* one way or another. Technically, `++i; ++i;` are "conflicting" expression evaluations, as they both modify the same memory location.

The [definition of "data race"](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#intro.races-21) only cares about particular kinds of conflicting actions. Specifically, "potentially concurrent conflicting actions."

Comment: hi @Nicol Bolas "they are unsequenced, at least one is performed by a signal handler, and they are not both performed by the same signal handler invocation" - what does a signal handler mean?

Comment: Hi @Nicol Bolas So, by simply having multithreading, is a conflicting action (representing a data race) already occurring? Thanks

Comment: @Daniel: I don't know what you mean. Part of the point of my answer is that "conflicting" evaluations are not *inherently* data races. It's simply a term that classifies the relationship between two expression evaluations. Data races require conflicting actions, but conflicts *alone* are insufficient.

Comment: @GeorgeMeijer: [Signal handlers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/signal).  You install a function as a handler with the `signal` function or some implementation-specific alternative (e.g. Unix `sigaction`), and your function gets called when the signal is delivered.  They're used for various things like Ctrl-C processing, `kill` termination requests, segmentation faults, asynchronous I/O, etc.  But the point is that a signal handler can be called asynchronously at any time, regardless of what the main code is doing.

Comment: hello, @Nate Eldredge thank you very much for the documentation + 1